# How to check from which action I came in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have asp.net mvc 4 application, where I need to do some action when I came from HomeController ActionResult DoSmth(). How can I check this?

Comment: Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471188/how-do-i-get-the-referrer-url-in-an-asp-net-mvc-action)

Comment: @BorHunter: Can you please re-write the question and give an example of what you are after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use

```
     Request.UrlRefferer
```

To do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following

`var controller = (string)this.RouteData.Values["controller"];
var action = (string)this.RouteData.Values["action"];`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if relevant, but if you want to make sure that action is rendered only from your code you can use attribute **[ChildActtion]**.

- Otherwise check this answer: [ASP.NET MVC - Check if request comes from another action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014202/asp-net-mvc-check-if-request-comes-from-another-action)